# Java FileInputStream using if

Tags: java, if-statement

the program I'm doing requires me to use FileInputStream to calculate the grade point of a course.

The class I created, Course, has a method:

```
public double getGradePoint ()
{
    if (letterGrade == "A+" || letterGrade == "A")
        gradePoint = 4.0;
    if (letterGrade == "A-")
        gradePoint = 3.7;
    if (letterGrade == "B+")
        gradePoint = 3.3;
    if (letterGrade == "B")
        gradePoint = 3.0;
    if (letterGrade == "B-")
        gradePoint = 2.7;
    if (letterGrade == "C+")
        gradePoint = 2.3;
    if (letterGrade == "C")
        gradePoint = 2.0;
    if (letterGrade == "C-")
        gradePoint = 1.7;
    if (letterGrade == "D+")
        gradePoint = 1.5;
    if (letterGrade == "D")
        gradePoint = 1.0;
    if (letterGrade == "F")
        gradePoint = 0.0;

    return gradePoint;
}
```

And in the test client I have:

```
String subject;
String number;
String letGrade;

Course course1 = new Course ("ENGL", "1111", "D+");
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream ("test transcript 1.txt");
Scanner readFile = new Scanner (file1);

while (readFile.hasNext ())
{
    course1.setSubject (readFile.next ());
    subject = course1.getSubject ();
    course1.setNumber (readFile.next ());
    number = course1.getNumber ();
    course1.setLetterGrade (readFile.next ());
    letGrade = course1.getLetterGrade ();
    course1.getGradePoint ();
    System.out.println (course1.toString ());
}
```

test transcript 1.txt contains:

```
COMP 1631   A-
ENGL 1101   B
MATH 1200   C+
```

But for some reason, when i use course1.getGradePoint (), it always returns as 0.0

After running the program:

```
COMP 1631   A-  (worth = 0.0)
ENGL 1101   B   (worth = 0.0)
MATH 1200   C+  (worth = 0.0)
```

I've tried using course1.getGradePoint () above the while command, like this:

```
String subject;
String number;
String letGrade;

Course course1 = new Course ("ENGL", "1111", "D+");
course1.getGradePoint ();

FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream ("test transcript 1.txt");
Scanner readFile = new Scanner (file1);

while (readFile.hasNext ())
{
    course1.setSubject (readFile.next ());
    subject = course1.getSubject ();
    course1.setNumber (readFile.next ());
    number = course1.getNumber ();
    course1.setLetterGrade (readFile.next ());
    letGrade = course1.getLetterGrade ();
    course1.getGradePoint ();
    System.out.println (course1.toString ());
}
```

Returns as:

```
COMP 1631   A-  (worth = 1.5)
ENGL 1101   B   (worth = 1.5)
MATH 1200   C+  (worth = 1.5)
```

It just won't work with readFile.next () for some reason.  If anyone could help me out, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of the if statements in getGradePoint I would store the letterGrade / gradePoint combination as a key value pair in a HashMap<String, Double>. In the getGradePoint method you would then simple do: return map.get(letterGrade);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-** `Objects` in Java are **compared using** `equals()`, and `String` is an `Object` in Java, so it follows the same rule.

**-** `==` will be used to **compare** `primitive` or to check if **two or more** `Object Reference Variables` are pointing to the **same Object on the heap or not.**

**-** So you should use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` (if case doesn't matters) to compare the `String` Objects.

**Eg:**

```
if (str1.equals(str2)){}
```

Comment: +1 This is better explanation. So, deleted mine.

Comment: Two String of same type cant exist in memory at same time right?? So the memory reference should match right?

Answer (score 0):

This code would have worked if he have not used file to get the grade.

since he is using files, the string object created will not be intern(). Which means that there exist two string objects of same type but in different memory references.

By interning the string you resolve it to any existing string of same type in the memory if it exist or create a new reference.

That's why the "A" which is got using file is not having the same reference as "A" which is created by using constructor.

He can make it work by making only one line code change of `(course1.getLetterGrade ()).intern()`

But it is always better to use equals for string comparision.